# Query to get number of records where 0, using 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table Structure**
[image]

**Table structure brief**

We have 2 tables **Weight** and **Weight_Sub**, they are both identical. Our users weigh-in every 2 days and every team have a captain. So after each weigh-in team captain adds the weight according to the date in the **Weight_Sub** table and for that we add records in **Weight** table with weight **0**. Once the team player accepts that score we delete them from **Weight_Sub** and update scores in main table i.e. **Weight**. E.g. If a player on 01/03/2015 was weighed 98KG we'll add there record in **Weight_Sub**= 98 and in **Weight**= 0. Once player will accept that weight then we will delete that row from **Weight_Sub** table and update weight in **Weight** table from 0 to 98.

I hope it makes sense.

**Problem**
We want to make a check when player accepts the score that did he missed any weigh-in. Like in the above table for 03/03/2015 in both tables the weight is 0,0 that means player missed a weigh-in. We want to get those missed weigh-in dates. The thing is we only want missed weigh-in dates which were missed after accepting the last weight, in this case on 07/03/2015.

So if you see the above image, player missed weigh-in on the 03/03/2015 but on 07/03/2015 he accepted the weight as 100KG. After that he missed 3 consecutive weighin's and then accepted on the 15/03/2015. So the query should return 3 dates i.e. 09/03/2015, 11/03/2015, 13/03/2015.

I know it can be done using PHP by running the loop and breaking when I find the accpted scores and get dates for missed weighin's but I'm looking for something for more efficient if there is.

Comment: Don't know if I understand it... you want get the dates when both weight are 0's?

Comment: Yes indeed but not all the dates when both weight are 0. We need dates when both weight are 0, checking from the last accepted weight i.e. when last weight which isn't 0. So yes you partially got that right.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return missed records before a given date.

```
select w1.ID, w1.Date, w1.Weight
from `WeightTable` w1
where w1.Date < '07/03/2015' and w1.Weight = 0
```